# How to represent multi valued subtype in the EERD?

Tags: sql, sql-server, erd

I'm trying to represent a question in the EErd. The question can be a true/false question or a multiple choice question. If it's a multiple choice question question then I will need to add its answers, so I've created a sub-type that has a choiceChar (a,b,c,d) and choiceValue:

[image: Question mcq EERD]

Now I'm wondering if I should use the multi-valued notation for the choiceChar and choiceValue attributes since each multiple choice questions will have more than one answer or should I leaved it as a single value since I will represent the choiceChar and the choiceValue at the same table.

My question is how to represent multi valued sub-type in the EERD to achieve the ability to have both a choiceChar & choiceValue?

Comment: Please edit your question , what RDBMS you use SQL Server ? or MySql? tag one. and add sample data.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server, though I think my question is more related to ERD stage before creating the tables

Comment: Can you explain the choiceValue and give examples of the values you want to record in it? Is choiceValue dependent on choiceChar or vice-versa?

Comment: You've indicated that Question is a weak entity set (double-bordered rectangle) and totally participating in a relationship (double line going to the left) as I would expect of a weak entity set in an identifying relationship, but you've given it its own identity (qId). What's up with that?

Comment: lets say the question is "what is the meaning of html?"
then I will add some rows at the mcq table for its choices
choiceChar  >> 'a' and choiceValue >> 'how to make lemon'
choiceChar  >> 'b' and choiceValue >> 'hyper text markup langue'
choiceChar  >> 'c' and choiceValue >> 'all of above'

Answer (score 0):

Based on your examples of choiceChar/choiceValue, I believe you have a functional dependency `choiceChar -> choiceValue`. This means that it's not correct to model the two elements as independent multi-valued attributes - rather, choices should be modeled as an entity set in a one-to-many relationship with questions.

[image: multiple choice question ERD]

I made choice a weak entity since I believe different questions can have choices with the same `choiceChar`, so we can identify choices by a compound key `(qId, choiceChar)`.

Physically, this is implemented like so:

[image: multiple choice question table diagram]